# How to remove MFC9700lpr:i386 package

Tags: wine, printing

I am trying to install Garmin Express, but I need to install WineTricks first, and I am getting this error when installing:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package mfc9700lpr:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

However, this was an old printer that I don't use anymore, so I could really get rid of it, but I am having no luck at doing so.  I have tried a lot of commands that I have found on here, about purging and removing, but still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried simply running `sudo apt remove mfc9700lpr` yet?

Comment: I was pretty sure that I tried that, but I did come home today, and gave that a try and it is still saying the same thing.                                                             
-----   travis@travis-HP-bedroom ~ $ sudo apt remove mfc9700lpr
[sudo] password for travis: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package mfc9700lpr:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.